# way other than joins Subqueries and Complex Joins?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, postgresql

is there an any other efficient way than joins, Subqueries and  Complex Joins  to query database tables with 1 to 1 or 1 to many relation.if there are any other way what are they where we can learn about them?

Comment: There is no other efficient way.

Comment: Well that was an efficient answer.

Comment: Although they may seem that complex, [here is a lengthy Q&A that I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) to try to make it more approachable. It has heaps of queries, results and detailed explanations of what is going on. It covers Joins, Subqueries and a lot more goodies. It should help you out a bunch I hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such no.

You can hide the complexity through, Views, Stored Procedures or ORMs, but relational databases use relations.